# How do you call a function from another component when navigating in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**What I want to do**

I want to use function `Refresh` in First, when navigating from Third to First.

**Class First**

```js
export default class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      checkedItems: [],
    };
  }

  Refresh = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await DB.getAllItems();

    const items = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      items.push(doc.data());
    });
    this.setState({
      items,
      checkedItems: [],
    });
  }
}
```

It navigates to Second from First.

**Class Second**

```js
export default class Second extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible: false,
    };
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
        <Third nav={this} />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Second has a child component, Third which is a modal.

**Class Third**

```js
export default class Third extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  navigateFirst = () => {
    this.props.nav.toggleModal();
    this.props.nav.props.navigation.navigate('First');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.navigateFirst}
        >
          <Text>Back To First</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In Third, it navigates back to First closing modal.

**Problem**

I don't want to use `componentDidUpdate` because First has checkbox.

If I use `componentDidUpdate`, every time I press checkbox, it triggers `Refresh`.

That is what I avoid.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it easier if you call the Refresh function everytime load First.js. Then when you return to First from Third, it auto trigger it.

**// First.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.Refresh();
  this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.Refresh)

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But nothing changed. When navigating from third to first, componentDidMount doesn't trigger.

Comment: @Ngoc Tuan Lam `componentDidMount` will only trigger first time render, LPFJ is back to the scene so it couldn't work.

Comment: But you could try his answer with `this.props.nav.props.navigation.push('First')`  instead of `navigate`, maybe it could work?

Comment: @高鵬翔 you are right, i attach the willFocus inside, the refresh function should trigger now everytime the page is focus.

Comment: @NgocTuanLam yeah, `willFocus` should work fine. Maybe have to remove at `componentWillUnmount` will be more perfect?

Comment: @高鵬翔 Thank you so much! I didn't know about ```willFocus```. Love you men.

Answer (score 0):

### You can achieve the desired behavior easily with componentDidUpdate without calling refresh on every props and state changes.

#### Third

```
export default class Third extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  navigateFirst = () => {
    this.props.nav.toggleModal();
    // this.props.nav.props.navigation.navigate('First');
   //instead of just .navigate('First') you can pass param  
this.props.nav.props.navigation.navigate('First',{isFromThird:true}) //like this

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.navigateFirst}
        >
          <Text>Back To First</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

#### In First.js just check for the param isFromThird

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
// React Navigation < 5
let isFromThird = this.props.navigation.getParam("isFromThird",false)

//React Navigation >= 5
let isFromThird = this.props.route.params?.isFromThird ?? false;

if(isFromThird){
this.Refresh()
}
```